# Collapse of THE wave-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction, wave-particle-duality, wavefunction-collapse

Are the wave-function and the quantum field the same?

If energy is in a quantum field - let's say the photon field for example. Somehow energy has been transferred from a source into the photon field. No photons exist yet though. Only when this energy interacts with other matter can we measure that the energy corresponding to a single photon or many photons was there. The wave-function is said to collapse when it interacts with matter. Obviously when energy is transferred from the photon field the field becomes inactive again. So is this the same thing?

I find it a little hard to reconcile (for myself) reactions that produce single photons with this definition. For example when a photon breaks down into an electron-positron pair do physicists think of this as energy transferring between the different fields?

To be blatant about it the statement would be "half the energy corresponding to a single photon transferred into the electron field (and the positron is half the combined energy in the same field moving in the opposite direction?)"

So the wave-function collapses and the energy enters another field?

Comment: Usually it's considered good form to wait a day or two before assigning an answer as accepted. Others may have further answers.

Comment: @puppetsock - thank you for informing me about the protocol : )

Comment: @puppetsock - I also see no reason though why my having accepted an answer would dissuade others from contributing with further answers if they have something to add to the understanding of the topic. We are here to share with each other after all. In future though I will definitely wait. I see your point and it would also be good manners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to have clear in one's thinking the different frames and contexes when looking at quantum mechanical tools.

Quantum mechanics is the same in all formalisms, based on the [postulates.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html). The foundations are the wavefunctions describing particles: Klein Gordon for bosons, Dirac for fermions, quantized maxwell's for photons.

In simple bound states, as the hydrogen atom, where a potential is known, or can be approximated for larger atoms, wavefunctions can be found and energy levels of bound states and transitions of energy levels.

For many particle states and for scattering particles off particles,  a wave function can theoretically be proposed, but the complexity of the collective potentials make *new mathematical tools*  necessary, **based on the postulates of quantum mechanics**

Quantum field theory (QFT) is one of the ways discovered that can allow calculations for complicated potentials and many body problems.

What are the fields in quantum field theories? they  are the plane wave solutions of the particles under study . These fields are supposed to permeate all of space time, at every ( x,y,z,t) point, on which creation and annihilation operators operate. They are used  to represent [a perturbative (series) expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) of the problem at hand. I.e, an expansion in series made with various mathematical tools to be normalized so that total probability is one. This we know as the expansion in Feynman diagrams which is a way to represent the integrals necessary for  calculations of measurable quantities.

So "collapse" which by the way is a misleading term in describing wavefunctions, means a change in the wavefunction as interactions happen.

Take this first order in the [expansion Feynman](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) diagram, for electron electron scattering

[image: ee]

"Collapse" of the wave function can be considered between input electrons and outgoing electrons.

[image]

This is [pair production](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Electron-Positron_nuclear_Pair_production_Feynman_Diagram.gif/220px-Electron-Positron_nuclear_Pair_production_Feynman_Diagram.gif) ( always needs an interaction with an electromagnetic  field from a nucleus or other field for momentum conservation)

The energy is transferred between external lines where four vectors with the invariant mass of the particle hold true. Energy and momentum variables within the integrations implied, are variable under the limits of integration. The fields in field theory are like a different type of coordinates on which the interaction can be modeled. There is no energy exchange with the fields that can be measured experimentally.

> So the wave-function collapses and the energy enters another field?

This mixes up the two systems, the simple wavefunction solutions ("collapse", and the coordinate system of fields plus annihilation and creation operators used for calculation of a series expansion )

Comment: Your answer and my brain... Sigh. There's a disconnect that may very well be my fault.  Can you explain more? Consider a very simple thing like the old example of a radioactive spec at the center of a sphere of phosphorescent material. The wave function for radiation is spherically symmetric. But we see only discrete spots of light, not a uniform glow. How does QFT give us that? And how is it consistent with the double slit experiment?

Comment: I'm in your debt for a great answer like that anna v - very cool

Comment: @puppetsock you are mixing the classcical framework with the quantum mechanical. The wavefunction for anything is a solution of the specific boundary conditions. specs of matter and phosphorescent material are classical when the radiation is viewed as sperical. The quantum mechanical wave function can be described with the density matrix formalism, which uses the multitude of indvdula atoms wavefunctions. The density matrix formalism is a different formalism/mathematics than field theory. The discrete spots of light are what necessitated  quantum mechanics, (among other observations)..

Comment: "Energy and momentum variables within the integrations implied" - - - - - - - what integrations?

Comment: complicated. see this  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04182.pdf

Comment: Please see section 6 of those very notes to confirm that there is **no** internal integration in this *tree level diagram.* This diagram is related by crossing symmetry to the one in your answer. Please note that the internal electron momentum is fixed by momentum conservation at the vertex: if the photon is ingoing then $p_{e} = p_{e^{+}} + p_{\gamma}$. Hence its momentum is clearly not integrated over.

Comment: In Feynman diagrams one only integrate over *undetermined* internal momenta, which occur only at **one loop order** and beyond. Another way of saying this is that momentum conservation at the vertex would imply a $\delta(p_{e} - p_{e^{+}} - p_{\gamma})$ with which the naive integral $\int d^{d}p_{e}$ can be removed.

Comment: Apologies. I was completely misunderstanding what question you were answering.